# How would I stub an fs callback's injected params to remove the need to touch the filesystem in a test suite?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, stub, sinon

I'm using Chai, Mocha, and Sinon for my testing framework.

Right now, I have a test for this working, but I actually have to create a directory and put files in it to get my tests to actually do something (this will be a large test suite, so doing things with all this diskIO is not ideal, to say the least).  How can I stub out the injection mechanism so that I don't have to touch the disk in the test?

I was thinking, in the example code below, some way to stub the `err` and the `files` parameters injected by the fs.readdir method.  That way, I avoid testing fs.readdir in my unit test.  I did some Googling and looked at the API Docs but I didn't find what I needed (or didn't recognize it).

Here is some sample code of what I'm talking about:

#### Function under test

```
function fsFxnWrapper(dir, callback) {
  var doSomeMutation = function (files) {
    ...
  };

  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
    callback(err, doSomeMutation(files));
  });
}
```

#### Sample Test Case

```
describe('When the directory has things'', function () {
  before(function () {
    ...
  });

  after(function () {
    ...
  });

  // I'm not sure how to write my stubs so that fs.readdir inside of the
  // fsFxnWrapper doesn't have to go out to the filesystem to retrieve something...
  it('should do the proper mutation on the files list', function () {
    var valueAfterMutation = [ /* the expected answer */];
    fsFxnWrapper('test/dir', function (err, files) {
      expect(files).to.deep.equal(valueAfterMutation);
      expect(err).to.equal(null);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is the only answer to pull the doSomeMutation function out so it can be tested in isolation from the rest of the fsFxnWrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider some mocking libraries if you work under Node.js: [node-mocks](https://github.com/vojtajina/node-mocks), [mock-fs](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs)

Comment: I'll take a look at those.  I had been reading the docs for Sinon because that's what seems to be popular, but maybe node-mocks will have something for this specific use-case.

Comment: After skimming over those, node-mocks doesn't look very mature or active, but mock-fs might work for this particular instance.

Comment: Sinon is a powerful universal mocking library. SInon.mock is a handy tool with which you can create your own mocks. However, you still need to create it yourself to provide some activity. The libraries mentioned give you a mock for a specific object/service/api. they are not universal but will handle exact task.

Comment: I ended up using `mock-fs`.  When using multiple functions from the `fs` module, I found myself mocking more and more of the `fs` module and getting to know more and more of its internals in the process.  Using the library just makes more sense, here.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could go about it would be to structure your module like this:

```
var Example = function (fs) {
  fs = fs || require('fs');

  this.fsFxnWrapper = function(dir, callback) {
    var doSomeMutation = function (files) {
      ...
    };

    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
      callback(err, doSomeMutation(files));
    });
  }
};

module.exports = Example;
```

Then you could mock `fs` before you pass it into the constructor of the module:

```
describe('When the directory has things'', function () {
  it('should do the proper mutation on the files list', function () {

    var Example = require('Example');
    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readir = function () {
      // your alternative implementation that doesn't touch the filesystem
    }

    var example = new Example(fs);
    var valueAfterMutation = [ /* the expected answer */];

    example.fsFxnWrapper('test/dir', function (err, files) {
      expect(files).to.deep.equal(valueAfterMutation);
      expect(err).to.equal(null);
    });
  });
});
```

I'd be curious to hear from others on this though because I've been using this approach in places, and while it works, I'm not sure if a more ideal solution exists.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think that would definitely be better than putting things on the disk and then cleaning them up.  I've noticed this (putting things out on the disk) creating concurrency issues in my test suite, which isn't going to work.